# ui-router and login url return state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here is a complicated question.
I am trying to create a returnState for when a user tries to access a page that requires authorisation.

So, I created some data on the state object which looks like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('account', {
    url: '/account',
    templateUrl: '/app/account/index.tpl.html',
    controller: 'AccountController',
    controllerAs: 'controller',
    data: {
        requireLogin: true,
        state: 'account' // tells the page to redirect here if not logged in
    }
});
```

and then I have this bit of code to run on stateChangeStart:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'AccountService', function ($rootScope, $state, account) {

    // On state change
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {

        var data = toState.data; // Get our state data
        var requireLogin = typeof data === 'undefined' ? false : data.requireLogin; // Check to see if we have any data and if so, check to see if we need login rights
        var user = account.current() // Get our current user

        // If we require login rights and we are not authenticated
        if (requireLogin && !user.authenticated) {

            // Get our current state
            var state = data.state || '';

            // Stop processing
            event.preventDefault();

            // redirect to the login page and pass the state parameter
            $state.transitionTo('login', { returnState: state });
        }
    });
}]);
```

and then on my loginController I have this function:

```
self.loginUser = function () {

    // Login
    self.login = service.login(self.model);

    // If we login properly
    self.login.promise.then(function (response) {

        // If we have a return Url
        if (returnState) {

            // Go to that url
            $state.go(returnState);
        } else {

            // Otherwise, Redirect to the home page
            $state.go('home');
        }
    });
};
```

The example I have shown works perfectly. But now I have found I have more complicated needs.
I have another set of states:

```
$stateProvider.state('designer', {
    url: '/:sport/designer',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: '/app/designer/designer.tpl.html',
    controller: 'DesignerController',
    controllerAs: 'controller'
}).state('designer.team', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl: '/app/designer/team.tpl.html'
}).state('designer.kit', {
    url: '/kit',
    templateUrl: '/app/designer/kit.tpl.html'
}).state('designer.design', {
    url: '/design',
    templateUrl: '/app/designer/design.tpl.html'
}).state('designer.refine', {
    url: '/refine',
    templateUrl: '/app/designer/refine.tpl.html'
}).state('designer.order', {
    url: '/order',
    templateUrl: '/app/designer/order.tpl.html'
}).state('designer.save', {
    url: '/save',
    templateUrl: '/app/designer/save.tpl.html',
    data: {
        requireLogin: true
    }
});
```

as you can see, this state and a few children and the last state (save) requires the user to be logged in. Because states inherit the parameters of their parents I should be able to do something like:

```
state: 'designer.save({ sport: :sport })'
```

but I get an error stating:

> > Error: Could not resolve 'desginer.save({ sport: :sport })' from state 'login'

now I am assuming this is because :sport is not being passed as a string, but I have tried alsorts and I cannot get this to work.
Is there a better way to handle routes?

I did try using the stateChangeStart function to get the state we were moving from, but I don't seem to be able to access that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user2847643 for his suggestion. I actually came up with a better way of handling this.
First, I modified the **login** state to this:

```
$stateProvider.state('login', {
    url: '/account/login',
    params: {
        returnState: '',
        returnParams: {}
    },
    views: {

        // the main template will be placed here (relatively named)
        '': {
            templateUrl: 'app/account/login/index.tpl.html'
        },

        // the child views will be defined here (absolutely named)
        'register@login': {
            templateUrl: 'app/account/login/register.tpl.html',
            controller: 'RegisterController',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        },

        // for column two, we'll define a separate controller 
        'login@login': {
            templateUrl: 'app/account/login/login.tpl.html',
            controller: 'LoginController',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see, this accepts two optional parameters.
I then modified the login function to this:

```
self.loginUser = function () {

    // Login
    self.login = service.login(self.model);

    // If we login properly
    self.login.promise.then(function (response) {

        console.log(returnState);
        console.log(returnParams);

        // If we have a return Url
        if (returnState) {

            // Go to that url
            $state.go(returnState, returnParams);
        } else {

            // Otherwise, Redirect to the home page
            $state.go('home');
        }
    });
};
```

which now correctly calls the **$state.go** function passing the state and the parameters (or an empty object).

And I actually put my logic for handling the returnStates in the **stateChangeStart** binding that I showed earlier, so this now looks like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams) {

    var data = toState.data; // Get our state data
    var requireLogin = typeof data === 'undefined' ? false : data.requireLogin; // Check to see if we have any data and if so, check to see if we need login rights
    var user = account.current() // Get our current user

    // If we require login rights and we are not authenticated
    if (requireLogin && !user.authenticated) {

        // Get our current state
        var name = toState.name;
        var params = toParams;

        // If our state is the login page (i.e. we accessed it directly)
        if (name === 'login') {

            // Set our state to the homepage
            name = 'home';
            toParams = {};
        }

        // Stop processing
        event.preventDefault();

        // redirect to the login page and pass the state parameter
        $state.transitionTo('login', { returnState: name, returnParams: params });
    }
});
```

And there we have it.

Comment: I'm sitting with this exact issue right now, and having only read through this, I have found one "bug" with this approach:

If the user arrives at http://example.com/profile which requires login, they'll be redirected to http://example.com/login... Sure, if they continue normally, everything works fine, however, if they refresh when landing there, any toState and toParams arguments will be lost

Comment: What I'm after is to be redirected to http://example.com/login?returnurl=/profile .... the problem is: I have no way to resolve the state url with the state params, without writing something myself to handle it

Comment: What I mean is: if I have a route: /members/{id:int}/profile?someVariable=&anotherVariable= ... when landing on /members/88/profile?someVariable=true&anotherVariable=sometimes ... how do i resolve my toState.url = /members/{id:int}/profile?someVariable=&anotherVariable along with {id: 88, someVariable: "true", anotherVariable: "sometimes"} to /login?returnurl=/members/88/profile?someVariable=true&anotherVariable=sometimes

Comment: it would be much appreciated if you can confirm my calculated guess

Comment: I have written a method to handle the merging of the state url with the toParams to get the returnUrl, works a charm, thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

First if we look at [the docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state) we can see `$state.go` accepts the following arguments:

- absolute state name
- parameters
- options

I cannot see it mentioned anywhere that it is leagal to put parameters directly into state name. So there we have the reason for the error message. `'designer.save({ sport: :sport })'` is *not* a correct absolute state name.

> Because states inherit the parameters of their parents

That means not only that you can access them but also that they are passed automatically in certain situations:

> Any parameters that are not specified will be inherited from currently
>   defined parameters. This allows, for example, going to a sibling state
>   that shares parameters specified in a parent state. Parameter
>   inheritance only works between common ancestor states, I.e.
>   transitioning to a sibling will get you the parameters for all
>   parents, transitioning to a child will get you all current parameters,
>   etc.

Thus you should not have to provide any parameters as long as you're in the `designer` state or any of it's children. If you're not, well then you need to find a way to pass the parameters as a second argument to `$state.go`.

Comment: yeah, that is a good point. I will have a look and see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you r3plica for this post. I was facing few issues and resolved it in following way. Someone can correct me, if I am wrong.

1. You should use ui-router latest version, old does not support params. I am using 0.2.13.
2. In the controller, you need to read the params as  $state.go($stateParams.returnState, $stateParams.returnParams)
3. In $stateChangeStart event, you need to pass parameters fromState, fromParams as well. This is used to check if the fromState is not login, so you skip reloading login page again and again.

   $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
          // var restrictedPage = $.inArray($location.path(),['/landing', '/list','/landing/users']);

   ```
       var data = toState.data;
       if(typeof toState.data !== 'undefined' && fromState.name !== 'login'){......}
      }
   ```